# Как добавить собственные скрипты в функцию add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts')?

Tags: wordpress

Стоит задача, при подключении своего шаблона для вывода определённой категории, полностью очистить содержимое функции `wp_head()`.

С этим отлично справляется функция `remove_all_actions('wp_head')`.

Но после этого мне необходимо подключить уже свои стили и скрипты в неё же (ранее очищенную).

Почему не срабатывает вот эта конструкция?

1) Вычищаю:

```
remove_all_actions('wp_head');
```

2) Добавляю свой файл стилей через стандартный хук `'wp_enqueue_scripts'`:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
  wp_enqueue_style('project-main', get_project_directory_url() .'/animals/styles.css', false, '0.0.0', 'all');
});
```

... пробовал даже так (тоже не срабатывает):

```
add_action('wp_head', function() {
  add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
    wp_enqueue_style('project-main', get_project_directory_url() .'/animals/styles.css', false, '0.0.0', 'all');
  });
});
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в очищенную функцию `wp_head()` заново начать добавлять свои файлы через `'wp_enqueue_scripts'`?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Никогда так не делайте

```
remove_all_actions('wp_head');
```

Вы ломаете функционал WordPress, о котором не имеете представления. В частности, следствием этого ковбойского кода является то, что вы запрещаете выполнение `wp_print_styles()` и `wp_print_head_scripts()`, которые висит на хуке `wp_head`:

```
add_action( 'wp_head',             'wp_print_styles',                  8    );
add_action( 'wp_head',             'wp_print_head_scripts',            9    );
```

(строки из файла `wp-includes/default-filters.php`).

Именно эти функции выводят скрипты в заголовке страницы. То, что вы пытаетесь сделать в вопросе, не работает, потому что функции `wp_enueue_style()` и `wp_enqueue_script()` не выводят стили и скрипты, а лишь ставят их в очередь. А вывод осуществляют `wp_print_styles()` и `wp_print_head_scripts()`, которые вы благополучно прибили.

Кроме того, вы прибили вывод тега `<title>`, запуск всех скриптов WP, в том числе необходимых для работы админки, feed, rss, канонические ссылки, иконку сайта, админ бар, коллбэки в хедер (я не знаю, что это за функционал и как он используется темами и плагинами), некоторые функции кастомайзера.

Я вообще сильно удивлюсь, если WordPress будет работать после такого удаления всех функций из `wp_head`.

Удалять из `wp_head` нужно только то, что вам действительно мешает. Надо искать вхождения `wp_head` в ядре и удалять ненужное через `wp_dequeue_script()` и `wp_dequeue_style()`.